# swipe to delete UITabelViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

i tried to do swipe to delete on table view cell, but after swiping that cell several times then only it is getting deleted. how to make it work smoothly(in one attempt swipe and delete)? my code is here :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var bId = Helper.businessId as String
    let param = ["id" : bId] as! [String : AnyObject]
    if editingStyle == .delete{
        print(Helper.memId)
        print("Deleted")

    var myDictionary = self.List[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    var bId : String!

    if myDictionary.allKeys.count>0
    {
        bId = myDictionary["id"] as! String
    }
    var bb = bId as String
            if editingStyle == .delete{
        print(Helper.memId)
        print("Deleted")
        Alamofire.request("http://api.noattabeta.com/api/v1/user/current/memberships/\(bb)", method: .delete, headers: ["Authorization":Helper.token]).responseString
            {response in
                print("In Response")

                switch response.result {
                case .success:

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: "Do You want to delete",preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok",style:UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler:{ (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })
                        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Cancel",style:UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler:{ (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        })

                        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                        myAlert.addAction(cancelAction)

                        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }}}
```

Comment: You need to wait till the server respond and in the meanwhile show a loader so that user knows that deletion is in process.

Answer (score 1):

First I wanted to point out that you're presenting the alert in the wrong place. You make a delete call on the API after it success you're asking if he or she want's to confirm. you have to ask it before you call delete

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

var bId = Helper.businessId as String
let param = ["id" : bId] as! [String : AnyObject]
if editingStyle == .delete{
    print(Helper.memId)
    print("Deleted")

var myDictionary = self.List[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
var bId : String!

if myDictionary.allKeys.count>0
{
    bId = myDictionary["id"] as! String
}
var bb = bId as String
        if editingStyle == .delete{
    print(Helper.memId)
    print("Deleted")

             let myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message: "Do You want to delete",preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
             let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok",style:UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler:{ (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                   // here you can call the delete if user accepts
                    Alamofire.request("http://api.noattabeta.com/api/v1/user/current/memberships/\(bb)", method: .delete, headers: ["Authorization":Helper.token]).responseString
        {response in
            print("In Response")

            switch response.result {
            case .success:

                   DispatchQueue.main.async {

                      // remove from your local array e.g
                      self.dataModel.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                      // Delete the row before you reload the tableView
                      self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)               
                      // Now reload your tableView
                      self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
              })

             myAlert.addAction(okAction)
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Cancel",style:UIAlertActionStyle.default,handler:{ (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                     self.tableView.reloadData()
              })

               myAlert.addAction(okAction)
               myAlert.addAction(cancelAction)

               self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
```